# Getting Iframe contents height AFTER LOAD via jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load

Basically I am trying to get the height of a series of < iframes > on my page and apply the height specifically to the < iframe > so there is no scrollbar. I've been through a dozen questions on here and none of them work correctly. I currently use the following code:

```
      $('#connectors_display').find('iframe.iframe_render').each(function() {
        var current_iframe = $(this);

        $(current_iframe).load(function() {
          var iframe_height_body =  $(current_iframe).contents().find('body').height();
          var iframe_height_html =  $(current_iframe).contents().find('html').height();
          var iframe_height 

          if (iframe_height_body > iframe_height_html){
              iframe_height = iframe_height_body
          }
          else {
              iframe_height = iframe_height_html
          }

          $(current_iframe).height(iframe_height);
        });

      });
```

Some notes:

- "iframe_render" is the class of the iframes I am targeting.
- With my current code I get huge values 1000s of pixels larger and small values 1000 pixes smaller.
- My fear is the calculations are being done before the ifame is comple loading
- I get 2 values, one for < body > and one for < html > because I hear they give different values and I want the larger one to be safe.

Here is the website I am working on:

http://fancentric.org/cc/highlights/?open=tab_contentconnectors

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Why oh why oh why oh why are you using IFRAME's to do this? Surely if you have permission to use whatever content you're IFRAME-ing, you could instead inject it directly into your own content.

Comment: Because then I have to deal with all the stylesheet issues that come along with the "parent" site. I need these to be completely agnostic to the "parent" site as far as styles go.

Comment: Why can't the "parent" site issue you with unbranded/unstyled content?

Comment: I apologize I don't understand what you mean. For example all the < p >, < table >, < div > and so on will inherit styles from the parent site. The iframed contest is an export of an email application we built and I don't want to mingle that HTML with the websites HTML.

Comment: Not if you get *unstyled* content handed to you (i.e: the authors of the content have already produced 'sanitised' content for public reproduction). If you don't have that kind of relationship with the parent site, how specifically are they allowing you to use their content?

Comment: I built both the website and the email content so permissions is not an issue. Ripping out all the styles from the email content would be a huge undertaking to get them render consistently with the current output. Even if I did that the tags them selves would still inherit styles from the parent site which I would have to write additional CSS rules to overwrite. This seems like a huge undertaking and doesn't seem scalable as we add more examples. All of the styles are automatically done via our app so hand creating them seems redundant. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: No. I think I misunderstood what you meant by 'parent'. However, as you're in control of the content, perhaps you can avoid inheriting the 'parent' site's styles by explicitly encoding the correct computed styles as `style` parameters on each tag in your embedded content (this would be tricky). I'll try to think of a simple (automatic) way to do this with JavaScript....

Comment: Sorry, yes "parent" was referring to the container Content (CTRL) website. The iframed content are email html exports from another application we built that I saved as flat files and reference on our server.

Comment: The pseudo code would be something like: `(1)` create a hidden IFRAME for the piece of pre-formatted embedded content. `(2)` using Javascript, visit each element in that IFRAME's DOM. For each element, pull out all the 'applied' styles using `getComputedStyle`. Remove any `class`/`id` attributes on the elements. Re-inject the applied styles as a `style` attribute on each element. `(3)` From the 'parent' frame, pull out the now 'cleansed' HTML and inject it into the 'parent' DOM inside a wrapper DIV. `(4)` Delete the hidden IFRAME...

Comment: From there you have all the normal CSS tools at your disposal to achieve your layout goals.... Like I said.... tricky.

Comment: But wouldn't this still inherit styles from the "parent" site? For example, If I don't explicitly set padding on a <p> tag the parent site will inject it's CSS.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. By determining the "computed" styles (usually there are DOZENS) and *explicitly* setting them (ALL) via the `style` property, you make your embedded content impervious to CSS inheritance. There's only one exception... `!important` rules. If you don't use those in the 'parent' site, there's no problem.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. That does make sense. It's an idea for sure. Thanks for the creativity.